# Why does fft-js not give a frequency bin for fs/2

Tags: javascript, fft, frequency

I am performing a fft on a wave consisting of two simple sine waves with fft-js. The number of samples is 512 and the running time is 16 seconds. So the sample frequency is 32Hz. When looking into the resulting frequency this goes up to 15.9375 instead to the sample frequency divided by two (16 Hz). Why is this the case and is there a way to include the sample frequency divided by two?

Comment: Information at fs / 2 is generally not useful since it's the Nyquist frequency and it will have been significantly reduced in amplitude by your anti-aliassing filter.

Comment: Your question is well posed and legitimate. The FFT will give you a result where you expect it, but this could depend on the implementation (always try higher level environments first to check the math, say Mathematica, matlab, numpy) .  Check whether you have a frequency bin at -16 Hz.  Since the FFT wraps around, this is the value to use.

Comment: Minor point. Technically the `sampling rate` is 32 Sa/sec. It's better not to use the term `sampling frequency`, because the highest frequency we sample is 16 Hz.

Comment: 16-15.9375 = 0.0625. 1/0.0625= 16. So you were right to be suspicious, the program gave you the (n-1)th frequency only.

Comment: We can only sample frequencies **lower** than half the sampling frequency. A signal at exactly half the sampling frequency is aliased.

Comment: @CrisLuengo  The question was about where to find the bin, not the interpretation of the amplitude in it. You'd want to know e.g. that the amplitude is indeed very low.

Answer (score 0):

This short Python example shows that you were right to look for the highest frequency and it is at a nonintuitive place. The Nyquist Frequency for the FFT is actually at the other end of the frequency vector:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
%matplotlib inline

T=1 # secs
d=0.1 # secs
n=int(T/d)

t=np.arange(0,T,d)  
print(f'time : {t}')

freq=np.fft.fftfreq(n,d)
print(f' frequencies (unshifted) : {freq}')

sfreq=np.fft.fftshift(freq)
print(f' frequencies (shifted) : {sfreq}')
```

output:

```
time : [0.  0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9]
 frequencies (unshifted) : [ 0.  1.  2.  3.  4. -5. -4. -3. -2. -1.]
 frequencies (shifted) : [-5. -4. -3. -2. -1.  0.  1.  2.  3.  4.]
```

Now Paul is also right, that a proper use of the FFT should use anti-aliasing measures such that ideally the energy at the very highest frequencies are almost zero.

Comment: Proper anti-aliasing would put the frequency at Nyquist to zero, as that frequency band is aliased by the sampling.

Comment: Yes, `proper antialiasing` would put the amplitude at the Nyquist frequency to zero, but I haven't seen an experimental case where this is possible. Noise can always happen after your filter and before digitization.   The question was not about the amplitude at the Nyquist frequency, but where to find the amplitude at the Nyquist frequency.